# Verifying PEP8 in exported iPython notebook code

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, pep8

Is there a way to verify that an iPython notebook's code is PEP8 compliant, after it has been exported as an `.ipynb` file?

Answer (score 1):

`.ipynb` files are pure json, you can read it, concatenate all the cells, and run pep8 on it. On the other end, getting the correct cell number/line number to "fix" them would be slightly more difficult.

I'm not aware of any project the does it right now.

Comment: Looks like it's time to roll up my sleeves and write some code!

Comment: I guess you could also convert it to `.py`  ( Download as ) or ( `--script` ) and then run a pep8 !

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the `pep8.py` file to extract out the python code from the json and check it for `pep8` compatibility. The [modified pep8.py file](https://github.com/rvraghav93/pep8/blob/ipynb/pep8.py).

Use it without installing ( since it has not yet been reviewed ) :

```
python pep8.py notebook.ipynb --format="ipynb"
```

`--format="ipynb"` is used to get the line number offset on a per-code basis, instead of a cumulative numbering.

I've sent a [Pull Request](https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/pull/337) for the same on github.

Though I am not sure whether it would be merged, I feel you might find the same useful. Try it out !

EDIT: Looks like the PR won't get merged.

Comment: Even if not accepted this is definitively usefull. You should post on IPython-dev ML, you will make some happy peoples.